# how to combine multiple facebook wall posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image: snapshot 1][image: snapshot 2] 
I am publishing wall post on my fan page using GraphApi successfully , When I have to post something i post 5 to 6 posts at a time and the fan of my page in his news feed sees consecutive 5-6 different posts. What actually I am trying to achieve that when i post on my wall and when it reflects on my fan's wall then he should see in his news feed my 5 to 6 feeds gets combined one under another like  Facebook Collections, rather 5-6 different posts

I have attached two snapshots the above snapshot is what actually happening and the another snapshot is of what i really trying to achieve but couldnt.
I know it can be done using Facebook Collections but i am using a facebook page and actions can't be published on pages so what are other options.

Comment: There’s no way for you to influence that; Facebook decides what and where they group stuff or not.

Comment: CBroe isnt there any way to use collections on page. Example in the above snapshot The name Sonam Saxena is a profile cant it be a page.

Comment: Collections are for Open Graph actions, and those are meant to be undertaken by real people. No, there is no way.